# Trouble with USB keyboard using an Arduino Leonardo

Tags: arduino, keyboard, usb

I have a "mystery box" that I know very little about. I need to get the [Arduino Leonardo](https://store.arduino.cc/arduino-leonardo-with-headers) to function with the box while it's in BIOS setup. I downloaded the [USBSerPassThruLine](https://github.com/gdsports/usb-metamorph/tree/master/USBSerPassThruLine) project from GitHub and that appears to work with every BIOS setup known to mankind except for my special box.

Every keystroke is accompanied by an implicit <kbd>Shift</kbd>. So if I call Keyboard.press('a') I get 'A'. Or for Keyboard.press('3') I get '#'.

I've tried being as direct as possible with my own simple press() routine:

```
void sendReport(KeyReport* keys)
{
    HID().SendReport(2, keys, sizeof(KeyReport));
}

KeyReport rawdata;
size_t press()
{
    uint8_t i;

    memset(&rawdata, 0, sizeof(KeyReport));

    //#define KEY_MOD_LCTRL  0x01
    //#define KEY_MOD_LSHIFT 0x02
    //#define KEY_MOD_LALT   0x04
    //#define KEY_MOD_LMETA  0x08
    //#define KEY_MOD_RCTRL  0x10
    //#define KEY_MOD_RSHIFT 0x20
    //#define KEY_MOD_RALT   0x40
    //#define KEY_MOD_RMETA  0x80

    //   rawdata.modifiers = KEY_MOD_RSHIFT;

    for (i=0; i<6; i++) {
        rawdata.keys[i] = KEY_1 + i;
    }

    sendReport(&rawdata);
}
```

All to no avail.

I still get: '!@#$%^' (instead of '123456')

Any ideas?

BTW, the strangle thing is that this BIOS setup works with any USB keyboard I plug into the box. Is there some older standard this box could be using?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to get it to work:

```
   if (first_time) {

     first_time = 0;

     memset(&rawdata, 0x0, sizeof(KeyReport));

     rawdata.keys[0] = KEY_CAPSLOCK;
     sendReport(&rawdata);
     releaseAll();
     delay(100);

     rawdata.keys[0] = KEY_CAPSLOCK;
     sendReport(&rawdata);
     releaseAll();
     delay(100);

     rawdata.keys[0] = KEY_LEFTSHIFT;
     sendReport(&rawdata);
     releaseAll();
     delay(100);
   }
```

As to why this works? Who knows?

BTW, this has *zero* to do the Arduino board and everything to do with that p.o.s. box.